# Docker Compose on Windows 10 Home cannot find any files

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to learn Docker and Docker Compose to set up a small example node/express server. I am running Docker toolbox on Windows 10 Home. Below is my project structure

```
root/ 
   docker-compose.yml
   Dockerfile
   index.js
   package.json
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . .
RUN npm install --quiet
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  node:
    build: .
    working_dir: /usr/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    expose:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "node index.js"
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

and this is my index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I have mixed together various examples found on docs for each of the components. But I couldn't get it to run. When I do `docker-compose up` I get the following :

```
$ docker-compose up
Building node
Step 1/5 : FROM node:8
8: Pulling from library/node
61be48634cb9: Pull complete
fa696905a590: Pull complete
b6dd2322bbef: Pull complete
32477089adb4: Pull complete
febe7209ec28: Pull complete
4364cbe57162: Pull complete
ace5c680ff94: Pull complete
4acd6a9b7a48: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7b65413af120ec5328077775022c78101f103258a1876ec2f83890bce416e896
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:8
 ---> 82c0936c46c1
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /usr/app
 ---> Running in 454ed6735e6e
Removing intermediate container 454ed6735e6e
 ---> 62d35be2db4c
Step 3/5 : COPY package.json .
 ---> fdbb25021d83
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install --quiet
 ---> Running in e535ef0bc18f
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 48 packages from 36 contributors and audited 121 packages in 3.179s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container e535ef0bc18f
 ---> 1a61e872c386
Step 5/5 : COPY . .
 ---> 56e765cf1c3c
Successfully built 56e765cf1c3c
Successfully tagged root_node:latest
WARNING: Image for service node was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating root_node_1 ... done
Attaching to root_node_1
node_1  | module.js:550
node_1  |     throw err;
node_1  |     ^
node_1  |
node_1  | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/app/index.js'
node_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
node_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
node_1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
node_1  |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
node_1  |     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
root_node_1 exited with code 1
```

I did come across my googling that there is some issue with Windows and file permissions but I couldn't find anything more detailed about this.

EDIT 1 : I have removed volume from docker-compose.yml and it works fine when I run with Docker CE for MacOS. The same thing cannot still find index.js in Windows with Docker tools

Comment: Same problem here.. in windows sometimes it helps to run something as administrator to solve permissions problems (right click => run as administrator). If you're running from a console, start the console as administrator (for cmd search it up with Win+s the right click)

Comment: it says file is not where it is supposed to be. add 'RUN pwd' 'RUN ls' in you Dockerfile to visually see what is happening.

Comment: I have tried that, pwd shows the right path where its supposed to be, ls shows only node_modules and package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the below.

In your index.js, expose port is 3000, so we will expose the same in the DockerFile.

In docker-compose.yml, 5000 to 3000 mapping of port is done. Where 5000 will be host (Windows) and 3000 client (Linux).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . . 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:3000"
```

Comment: It couldn't even find index.js - so i am quite sure this is not the issue

Comment: Yes it is not about the ports. The code i have posted worked with windows 7.

Comment: Yes it is not about the ports. The code i have posted worked with windows 7. Did you try removing "working_dir" from docker-compose.yml? just that it is already mentioned in the Dockerfile.